# troubleshooting jquery/ajax json data retrieve

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, json, firebug

I have the following code uploaded into a tomcat server the code suppose to retrieve information from other server,  for some reason this is not happening there is no reply from the other server the following is code  I get the error function alert"handshake didn't go through"

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var home_add='http://mywebsite.net:3300/gateway';
    $('#handshake').click(function(){
         alert(" sending json data");
         $.ajax({                 /* start ajax function to send data */ 
             url:home_add,
             type:'POST',
             datatype:'json',
             contanttype:'text/json',
             async: false, 
             error:function(){ alert("handshake didn't go through")}, /* call disconnect function */
             data: {
                 "supportedConnectionTypes": "long-polling",
                 "channel": "/meta/handshake",
                 "version": "1:0"
             },
             success: function(data) {
                 $("p").append(data+"<br/>");
                 alert("sucessful handshake");
             }                    
         });
     });
});
```

I checked the firebug net panel and I got the following request header sent but no response and there are no xhr please send me ur feedback

```
mywebsite.net:3300
User-AgentMozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101209 CentOS/3.6-2.el5.centos Firefox/3.6.13
Accepttext/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Languageen-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encodinggzip,deflate
Accept-CharsetISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive115
Connectionkeep-alive
Originhttp://127.0.0.1:8080
Access-Control-Request-Me...POST
```

Comment: `contanttype:'text/json'` should be `contenttype:'text/json'` (*e instead of a*).

Comment: and finally, remember to use the `;` where appropriate. (*you are missing 3 in you code*)

Comment: possible duplicate of [troubleshooting help jquery/ajax/json no http response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513276/troubleshooting-help-jquery-ajax-json-no-http-response)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you probably have an issue with cross-domain scripting.  If the domain you want to get data from isn't the same as the domain of your site you will need to use JSONP to get data from it.